# Using both Google Signin and Firebase auth require login twice?

Tags: authentication, google-api, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-api-js-client

I ran into an probably, to some users, confusing issue:

I'm using in my application `Firebase` to store the users data etc. and to have the user's data protected I use the build in `Google Authentication`. I recognized that I can define `scopes` at this signIn process, which the user can/should allow, but I although noticed that you can't ask for ALL of the Google Scopes/Services, (all with `Firebase` built in functionality)

so I have to use the `Google JS Library` as well for authentication, to access the rest of the User data (I want to show the user in my Web-App) stored on `Google`.

And maybe it could be kind of confusing if the `Google signin popup` shows **twice**, one auth to `Firebase` and another auth to `Google API's`.

My question is, Is there a way to, maybe hand over the `access_token` at the `Firebase signin process` (or vice versa), that I don't have the user signin **twice** and the `Google popup` shows up only **once**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `authWithOAuthToken` with the token you get back from Google auth: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthtoken.html. From there:

> This method accepts either a single string argument for OAuth credentials (such as an OAuth 2.0 bearer access token) or an object (such as a set of OAuth 1.0a credentials). Logging in with Facebook, GitHub, and Google with an OAuth token requires just a string access token:

```
// Authenticate with Facebook using an existing OAuth 2.0 access token
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithOAuthToken("facebook", "<ACCESS-TOKEN>", function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

The sample from the docs uses facebook, but the same applies to Google tokens.

Comment: If I'm using the Polymer `firebase-auth` element does it work there too?